# Visual Studio SQL Server 2016 database project and Temporal Tables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, database-project

Is there a way to enable temporal tables in a Visual Studio SQL Server 2016 database project? I cannot find a way to get this to work. I guess it could be a compatibility issue, the only way I've found is to enable the table in the post deployment script, but then on the next deploy, the script generates drops for the columns in question.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and SSDT are you using? What is the *exact* behavior? Are you saying that trying to deploy to an existing database generates DROP statements for existing columns without generating temporary tables? Going through temp tables *is* the safest option

Comment: What changes did you try to deploy?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. SSDT already has a template for temporal tables. Modifying the table generates the expected schema modification statements that first copy data to a temporary table to avoid data loss

Comment: I realize this is a very old post, but I had a similar issue. It turned out that the problem had nothing to do with temporal tables. That was just what the Schema Compare flagged as an issue. The true problem was that my database project would not compile because my database included references to other databases. I had to add database projects for all of the databases referenced, add database references to each database referencing other databases, and change the database name to a variable in the sql code calling the other database.

Answer (score 0):

Temporal tables *are* supported. The latest versionof SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 already contains a temporal table template that adds the `WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON(HISTORY_TABLE=[dbo].[MyTempTable_HISTORY], DATA_CONSISTENCY_CHECK=ON))` clause to the table creation script and creates the history table.

Modifying the table generates the same script that is generated when modifying any other table to avoid data loss - copy the data to a new temporary table, rebuild the original table, then copy the data back.

The only "strange" behavior is that the *history* table is recreated even for rename refactorings, which generate an `sp_rename` command, eg:

```
GO
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'[dbo].[MyTempTable].[Name]', @newname = N'Name1', @objtype = N'COLUMN';


GO
PRINT N'Starting rebuilding table [dbo].[MyTempTable_HISTORY]...';


GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tmp_ms_xx_MyTempTable_HISTORY] (
```

Comment: Does this work even with "GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START" columns?

Comment: Does what work? The template does contain the period columns and they do have the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START/END` clause. You can change their names to whatever you want before publishing.